# How to extract the value between the brackets in Python

Tags: python

I have a huge string and I am trying to parse it. What I want to do is read the `clk` (clock) values. Is there any way to extract this text(the text between the {[ ]}, in a Pythonic way?

1. e4 {[%clk 1:23:29]} c5 {[%clk 1:30:39]} 2. Nf3 {[%clk 1:23:32]} d6
   {[%clk 1:30:58]} 3. d4 {[%clk 1:23:50]} cxd4 {[%clk 1:31:21]}

The goal is to take the `clk` values and store them in a list.

Comment: You can beat it to death with a hand-built parser, or use a `regex` (regular expression) to pick out the stuff you want.  If you Google the phrase "Python regex", you’ll find tutorials that can explain it much better than we can in an answer here.  [Here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) is a start.

Comment: Yea that's exactly what I was trying to figure out was how to use regex to solve this problem. Thanks a lot for the link will definitely read into it!

Comment: You might also try for a full solution with a search for "Python chess notation parser".

Comment: When you get to a resolution, please remember to up-vote useful things and accept your favourite answer (even if you have to write it yourself), so Stack Overflow can properly archive the question.

Comment: I was looking at the pgn parser by python but there is a lot data that it would not be capturing that I actually have in my files due to the inconsistency of the chess world ;(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you can't have bracketed values inside other bracketed values, it's easy enough to capture each bracketed value with regex:

```
import re

s = """1. e4 {[%clk 1:23:29]} c5 {[%clk 1:30:39]} 2. Nf3 {[%clk 1:23:32]} d6
{[%clk 1:30:58]} 3. d4 {[%clk 1:23:50]} cxd4 {[%clk 1:31:21]}"""

results = re.findall(r"{\[%clk (.*?)\]}", s)
print(results)
```

Result:

```
['1:23:29', '1:30:39', '1:23:32', '1:30:58', '1:23:50', '1:31:21']
```

Quick explanation of the regex pattern:

```
{       #literal curly bracket
\[      #literal square bracket
%clk    #literal "%clk "
(.*?)   #match any number of characters, and capture them for the output
\]      #literal square bracket
}       #literal curly bracket
```

Comment: With regex how would I extract the move now? The move being e4, c5, d6 etc. I am a little confused on how regex works. It is string manipulation but what is exactly happening on the compiler level?